# Does IE9 RTW support the placeholder attribute on input elements?

Tags: html, input, internet-explorer-9, placeholder, rtw

A bunch of sites mention support in IE9, but I assume this was something that appeared in the Betas, or RC. It doesn't appear to be supported in IE9 final. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, placeholder text for form elements was never implemented for IE9. It is easily (and commonly) done with JavaScript.

Placeholder support was [added in IE10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772942(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Fortunately, there's a fix: http://kamikazemusic.com/quick-tips/jquery-html5-placeholder-fix/

(found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366021/placeholder-in-ie9)