# Text field on focus, with page load, with text that removes with type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple text field on my page, with the initial text value of '*Enter your Email*'. When the page loads, I automatically set the focus to this box, using the following:

```
<body onLoad="document.emvForm.EMAIL_FIELD.focus()">
```

I would like to make it so that when the user starts to type into the box, it clears the text, as opposed to clearing the text on-focus.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<input type="text" id="textField" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Set Text to be Default //
        var txtVal = 'Enter Your Email Address';
        $('#textField').val(txtVal).focus();

        // On Focus //
        $('#textField').focus(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == txtVal) $(this).val('');
        });

        // on Blur //
        $('#textField').blur(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val(txtVal);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wpZ8n/

I hope this helps!

Comment: He want to make my simple text field - set to focus on page load

Comment: This will hide the text when the box have focus, are he not asking only to hide when there is information entered?

Comment: This will hide the text on focus and only revert to the default text if no information is entered which is what I believe he is asking for.

Comment: Thanks - but it doesn't seem to be set to on focus on page load?

Answer (score 0):

You gonna have to use a `<span>` or `<label>` that you position on top of the simple text field, and then monitor if any text has been entered in the input field. If so hide the `<span>` or `<label>`

Answer (score 0):

In modern (HTML5-compliant) browsers, this functionality can be added by simply using the `placeholder` attribute, as shown below:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email" />
```

Modern browsers, unfortunately, do not include IE9. In order to make this work in IE9 and prior, you can use the following script (as an example):

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

(credit to the answer at this answer: [Placeholder in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366021/placeholder-in-ie9), which also lists other various ways to do it in IE, and gives comparison in the answers)

Answer (score -3):

Use jQuery

```
<input class="em" type="text" name="email" value="Enter your Email"/>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $(".em").focus();
    });

    $(".em").keypress(function() {
          var val = $(this).val(); 
          if (val == 'Enter your Email') {
              $(this).val('')
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your function will blank the input field even if someone has typed something in; not just the default message.

Comment: He wants the text to disappear when the user starts typing, if you tab to that input, it is not going to take clear the text box

Comment: OK try this. sorry i don't test first ;)