# How to create a jquery textbox with watermark?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I'm trying to create a textbox with jquery watermark, I was able to create in my Asp.net application but what I want to do is create a non-asp.net version which I can use simple html web pages or PHP written application. I was tried changing the codes but it doesn't work.

(What it does is the text of the watermark comes from the 'title' attribute of the input)

Anyway here's my from asp.net code:

Code for the aspx page:

```
 <div id="TableWrapper">
    <table class="style1" runat="server" id="FormTable">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <h1>Get in touch with us</h1>
          <p>Use the form below to get in touch with us. Enter your name, e-mail address, and your home or business phone number to get in touch with us.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Name
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter your name" CssClass="InputBox"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Name" CssClass="ErrorMessage" ErrorMessage="Enter your name">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          E-mail address
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="EmailAddress" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter your e-mail address" CssClass="InputBox"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="EmailAddress" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Enter an e-mail address">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="EmailAddress" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid e-mail address" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          E-mail address again
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmEmailAddress" runat="server" ToolTip="Confirm your e-mail address" CssClass="InputBox"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmEmailAddress" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Confirm the e-mail address">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="EmailAddress" ControlToValidate="ConfirmEmailAddress" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Retype the e-mail address">*</asp:CompareValidator>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Home phone number
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="PhoneHome" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter your home phonenumber" CssClass="InputBox"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="ValidatePhoneNumbers" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Enter your home or business phone number" OnServerValidate="HomePhoneCustom_ServerValidate">*</asp:CustomValidator>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Business phone number
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="PhoneBusiness" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter your business phonenumber" CssClass="InputBox"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Comments
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="Comments" runat="server" Height="78px" TextMode="MultiLine" ToolTip="Enter your comment here" CssClass="InputBox"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Comments" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Enter a comment">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:Button ID="SendButton" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="Send_Click" />
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" CssClass="ErrorMessage" HeaderText="Please correct the following errors before you press the Send button:" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="Message" runat="server" Text="Message Sent" Visible="False" CssClass="Attention" />
<p runat="server" id="MessageSentPara" visible="false">Thank you for your message.
We’ll get in touch with you if necessary.</p>



  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
  <ProgressTemplate>
    <div class="PleaseWait">Please Wait... </div>
  </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.updnWatermark.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
/*
$(':input[type=text], textarea').each //selector
(
function () { //function

var newText = 'Please enter your ' +$(this).parent().prev().text().toLowerCase().trim(); //gets the text of the previous element

$(this).attr('value', newText);

}).one('focus', function(){     //one will be done once, //.bind works for everytime the event is invoked

this.value = '', this.className = ''}).addClass('Watermark').css('width', '300px'); //alternate this.class ''
*/





/*
Notice how there’s no need to select any items; you just call the updnWatermark method on the jQuery
object (using its $ shortcut) without specifying any selectors. The updnWatermark method then scans
the form looking for form fields that have a title attribute. You can optionally pass in a CSS class that
defines the presentation of the text labels. In this example, the .Watermark and .Watermark label
selectors define the position and color of the watermark text that is placed on top of the text boxes.
*/


$.updnWatermark.attachAll({ cssClass: 'Watermark' });

$('form').bind('submit', function()
{
if (Page_IsValid)
{
$('#TableWrapper').slideUp(3000);
}
});


});










/* === pageLoad ===
pageLoad() is called after every UpdatePanel refresh
In the case of initialization code that should run once, $(document).ready() is the ideal solution.
The pageLoad method (which is part of the client-side ASP.NET AJAX Library) serves the same
purpose as jQuery’s document ready, with one exception: it also fires after a partial page update,
which is what takes place after you submit the form because of the UpdatePanel in the user control.
*/
function pageLoad()
{
$('.Attention').animate({ width: '600px' }, 3000).
animate({ width: '100px' }, 3000).fadeOut('slow');
}

</script>
```

Here's the code for the jquery watermark:

```
/*
* jQuery Watermark Plugin (v1.0.0)
*   http://updatepanel.net/2009/04/17/jquery-watermark-plugin/
*
* Copyright (c) 2009 Ting Zwei Kuei
*
* Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
*   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
*/
(function($) {
    $.fn.updnWatermark = function(options) {
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.updnWatermark.defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var $input = $(this);
            // Checks to see if watermark already applied.
            var $watermark = $input.data("updnWatermark");
            // Only create watermark if title attribute exists
            if (!$watermark && this.title) {
                // Inserts a span and set as positioning context
                var $watermark = $("<span/>")
                    .addClass(options.cssClass)
                    .insertBefore(this)
                    .hide()
                    .bind("show", function() {
                        $(this).children().fadeIn("fast");
                    })
                    .bind("hide", function() {
                        $(this).children().hide();
                    });
                // Positions watermark label relative to positioning context
                $("<label/>").appendTo($watermark)
                    .text(this.title)
                    .attr("for", this.id);
                // Associate input element with watermark plugin.
                $input.data("updnWatermark", $watermark);
            }
            // Hook up blur/focus handlers to show/hide watermark.
            if ($watermark) {
                $input
                    .focus(function(ev) {
                        $watermark.trigger("hide");
                    })
                    .blur(function(ev) {
                        if (!$(this).val()) {
                            $watermark.trigger("show");
                        }
                    });
                // Sets initial watermark state.
                if (!$input.val()) {
                    $watermark.show();
                }
            }
        });
    };
    $.fn.updnWatermark.defaults = {
        cssClass: "updnWatermark"
    };
    $.updnWatermark = {
        attachAll: function(options) {
            $("input:text[title!=''],input:password[title!=''],textarea[title!='']").updnWatermark(options);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

What I plan to have in my simple html page would be something like:

```
<input type="text" class="TheWaterMarkjquery" title="TheWatermark"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$.updnWatermark.attachAll({ cssClass: 'Watermark' });

});
```

I'm not really sure if it's possible to use this approach but I hope I can use this solution.

Sir/Ma'am your answers would be of great help and be very much appreciated.Thank you++

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS > `background-image` for this?

Comment: I can guess you are missing the CSS code for either `.Watermark` or `.updnWatermark`. Whatever you are using in your non-APS.Net application.

Answer (score 4):

Why cant you just use [this](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/)? Its jquery plugin and it is independent from ASP.NET or PHP. It will use HTML5 placeholder attribute if browser supports it and will fallback to other way of doing it in otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate reply sir, it's just that I want to have the same solution for each project wherein I can use it either in Asp.net and PHP. I'm currently a student and I aspire to become professional programmer/developer.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the `placeholder` attribute.  This is specific to HTML5 and I didn't see the question specifying *not* HTML5:

```
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Mail Account</legend>
  <p><label>Name: <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="John Ratzenberger"></label></p>
  <p><label>Address: <input type="email" name="address" placeholder="john@example.net"></label></p>
  <p><label>Password: <input type="password" name="password"></label></p>
  <p><label>Description: <input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="My Email Account"></label></p>
 </fieldset>
```

More information can be found here: [w3.org placeholder attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute)

Enabling the functionality for IE9, covered in another SO question:  [Placeholder in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366021/placeholder-in-ie9) and [Input placeholders for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522164/input-placeholders-for-internet-explorer)

Comment: hahaha, yah I forgot to write that. I already tried that but it doesn't work on IE9. I know there's a workaround for that but for now I want to stick with this solution as much as possible but thank you sir giving a solution.

Comment: There are jQuery plugins available that add support for this attribute in IE, too: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder is a pretty nice one that even keeps `.val()` working properly as it would in a HTML5-compatible browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="Name">


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // On page load, apply watermark to input
    $('#Name').dwaterm();
});
</script>


<script>
(function ($) 
    $.fn.extend({
        dwaterm: function () {
            // Add watermark to textbox

            return this.each(function () {

                // Define what happens when the textbox comes under focus
                // Remove the watermark class and clear the box
                var obj = $(this);
                $(this).focus(function () {

                    $(this).filter(function () {

                        // We only want this to apply if there's not
                        // something actually entered
                        return $(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == "Type here"

                    }).removeClass("watermarkOn").val("");

                });
                // Define what happens when the textbox loses focus
                // Add the watermark class and default text
                $(this).blur(function () {

                    $(this).filter(function () {

                        // We only want this to apply if there's not
                        // something actually entered
                        return $(this).val() == ""

                    }).addClass("watermarkOn").val("Type here");

                });


            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```