# placeholder not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [placeholder in ie9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366021/placeholder-in-ie9)

I'm using placeholder for my textboxes. The problem is that in firefox and chrome they show up but in IE9 it's not working. I searched on the internet but none of the solutions worked for me. Any ideas?

```
<input class="text" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" required /><br />
```

Comment: We need the code to help you. Without it, we haven't a clue what you are doing.

Comment: Let's ask a genie in a bottle. Wait - event the genie can't tell without the code.

Comment: I've edited my question..it's a simple placeholder tag. Don't know whats the fss about the code.:))

Comment: @Bibu The first fuss about it is, you are talking about the placeholder **attribute** not the **tag**. So without the code no-one really knows that you are meaning something different than what you are asking. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you mean the placeholder attribute, it is not supported in IE9: http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder. You will need to use another solution to mimic the behavior.

Answer (score 5):

IE9 doesn't support HTML5's placeholder.

You need to do it with javascript.

Check [this plugin](http://kamikazemusic.com/quick-tips/jquery-html5-placeholder-fix/).