# Placeholders are not displaying in IE8 for Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, placeholder

I am using Bootstrap for my project. The placeholders are displaying fine for all browsers except in Internet Explorer 8 and below.

Are there any solutions to get placeholder support in IE8?

Comment: Placeholders are'nt supported in IE, you have to use a value and set it on focus/blur etc. with javascript.

Comment: You can use a [`placeholder` attribute polyfill](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) to add support for the `placeholder` attribute in all browsers. IE doesn't support it below version 10.

Comment: you should accept one of the answers if they helped you

Comment: related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366021/placeholder-in-ie9/14981525

Answer (score 8):

you can use this plugin
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder
Even works in IE6

Answer (score 4):

you can use jquery watermark plugin for that

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Answer (score 2):

It should'nt be to hard to figure this out without a plugin, I'm guessing something close to this will do the trick:

```
var test = document.createElement('input');
if (!('placeholder' in test)) {
    $('input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != "" && this.value == "") {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
                   .css('color', 'grey')
                   .on({
                       focus: function () {
                         if (this.value == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                           $(this).val("").css('color', '#000');
                         }
                       },
                       blur: function () {
                         if (this.value == "") {
                           $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
                                  .css('color', 'grey');
                         }
                       }
                   });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: IE crashes on `if (!'placeholder' in test) {`

Comment: @pinouchon - it does'nt for me, but all you have to do if that is a problem, is wrap it in parenthesis and that should solve it. Added that to the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on from Rubens answer there is a demo here

http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder

Answer (score 1):

IE9 and below doesn't support the `placeholder` attribute. See [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder)

You can use [EZPZ hints](https://github.com/enriquez/ezpz-hint/) to supplement it though. Just load the script if the browser is IE

```
 <!--[if lt IE 10]>
      <script src="PATHTOFILE"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

EZPZ hints allows you to continue to use `placeholder` for modern browsers.

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search" />

$("input[type=text]").ezpz_hint();
```