# Change textarea content on click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How I can change my textarea content on click to be empty?

Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/QMfyP/

```
<textarea name="adventage" style="width:400px; border-radius: 3px; border-left: 4px solid #6C3" id="adventage" cols="45" rows="5">Share with everyone what are the advantages of this vehicle. </textarea>
```

The idea is on click to this area, it will be empty for typing new text.

Comment: `placeHolder` attribute is best and easy way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get that functionality using the `placeholder` attribute

```
<textarea placeholder='Share with everyone what are the advantages of this vehicle.'></textarea>
```

It is the standard and easiest way (no javascript involved, you can see it working in stackoverflow's search textbox in the top of this page!).

It will not work in old browsers though (IE9 and older), if you need it to work in those browsers you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366021/placeholder-in-ie9/6366162#6366162)

Comment: Good suggestion, but 'placeholder' isn't supported in IE 9 and earlier versions. If browser compatibility isn't an issue for you, this is perfect, otherwise use @adamb answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give the textarea a unique `id` (as you probably won't want to apply this to all textareas), e.g. `thetextarea`:

```
$("#thetextarea").click(function(){
   $("#thetextarea").empty();
});
```

Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QMfyP/8/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('YOURSELECTOR').click(function(e) {
    $('#adventage').empty();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/QMfyP/6/

HTML

```
<textarea class="my_textarea" name="adventage" id="adventage" cols="45" rows="5">Share with everyone what are the advantages of this vehicle. </textarea>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#adventage").click(function() {
  $(this).empty();
});
```

CSS

```
#adventage { width:400px; border-radius: 3px; border-left: 4px solid #6C3; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("textarea[name='adventage']").click(function({
        $(this).innerHTML("");
    }))
})
```

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

For the first time place holder works.But if you have sometext already inside that (`in case of editing`) do some `scripting`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#adventage').click(function(){
            $(this).val('');
        })

});
```