# input text field value on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

How can I make this in JQuery?
I need it to show the keyword if there is text in the value input.

http://imageshack.us/a/img849/3262/searchg.jpg

Comment: You want to make a picture with jquery, right? You have to elaborate a little more...

Comment: No... easier to describe

Comment: not for a blind person

Comment: If you do not care about supporting IE 8 or 9 you can use the HTML 5 `placeholder` attribute. If you do want to support IE 8 and 9 then you can use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) combined with [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/) to conditionally load a polyfill (such as [this](https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill)) to enable support for older browsers (such as IE 8 and 9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you're fine with not supporting 30% of the market (it's a HTML5 feature not supported in some legacy browsers) you can simply use

```
 <input value="" placeholder="Your placeholder text">
```

or otherwise add [this jquery plugin](https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim) to make it work everywhere.

Comment: Most of my users use IE8

Comment: Yeah, that's why I added the note about the jQuery plugin and additionally it is often seen graceful degradation, as not seeing the placeholder text only makes it less beautiful whilst not losing any functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [placeholder](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html) text?

```
<form>
  <input name="q" placeholder="Search uploads">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Most of my users use IE8

Comment: So look here, seems like the best jquery plugin for that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13281620/1414562  "Also it doesn't submit the placeholder text as a value when you submit your form "