# Setting placeholder att in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following code that run based on button click.

```
 function ClickYes() {      
      $('#<%=txtMsg.ClientID%>').attr('placeholder', 'Tell me more');
    }
```

The button is declared as the following

```
<button type="button" class="com-yes-btn2 feedback-btn-grey empx11b12" id="btnYes" onclick="javascript:ClickYes();">

</button>
```

the problem is that I need to set placeholder att dynamically based on event, in chrome and firefox the behavior is right, but when using IE9 placeholder attribute was not added.

how can I manage this cross browsers

Thanks

Comment: IE9 does not support the `placeholder` attribute but there are workarounds. Have a look at this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13281620/1423456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes *Placeholder is not supported by IE 9*. But you can look around to some alternative like javascript to achieve this very easily

```
<input type="text" placeholder="test" value="placeholder text" 
onfocus="if (this.value=='placeholder text') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'placeholder text'"/>
```

But you need to take care while using this approach as this approach setting the `value` of `textbox`. So when you will retrieve it, you will get the value. So whenever you will use it, you need to check for the placeholder value.

Your function would be like this

```
function ClickYes() {      
      // for modern browsers
      $('#txtMsg').attr('placeholder', 'Tell me more');

      // for older browsers
      $('#txtMsg').val('Tell me more');
      $('#txtMsg').css('color','#CCC');
    }
```

Now you need to handle the `focus` and `blur` event to make it complete like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtMsg").focus(function () {
       if ($(this).val() == 'Tell me more') {
          $(this).val('');
          $(this).css('color', 'black');
       }
    });
    $("#txtMsg").blur(function () {
       if (!$(this).val()) {
          $(this).val('Tell me more');
          $('#txtMsg').css('color', '#CCC');
       }
    });
 });
```

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh8b5/)**

[Js Fiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/q2Dka/1/)

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know IE9 does not support `placeholder` attribute so it is not functional in ie9.

[Placehoder attribute not supported in ie9](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder)

[You can follow this link to see the compatibility on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/)

so instead you can try this workaround:

```
function ClickYes() {      
  if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > 0){
     $('#<%=txtMsg.ClientID%>').val('Tell me more');
  }else{
     $('#<%=txtMsg.ClientID%>').attr('placeholder', 'Tell me more');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

IE9 doesn't supports the `placeholder` attribute, you will need to use the `blur` & `focus` events to simulate this functionnality.

```
function ClickYes() {

    var element = $('#<%=txtMsg.ClientID%>');

    // default action (on moderns browsers) 
    var placeholder = function() {
        element.attr('placeholder', 'Tell me more');
    };

    if (navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE [\d.]+/)) {
        // if MSIE: we override this function
        placeholder = function() {
            var placeholderText = 'Tell me more';
            element.val(placeholderText);
            element.blur(function(){
                $(this).val() == '' ? $(this).val(placeholderText) : false;
            });
            element.focus(function(){
                $(this).val() == placeholderText ? $(this).val('') : false;
            });
        };
    };

    placeholder(); // we call the created function
}
```

Source: [placeholder is not working in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696646/placeholder-is-not-working-in-ie9)

Answer (score 1):

I use place-holder.js,It is easy to use:
[PlaceHolder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder)

you can use it only by refrenced to jquery and placeholder.js and below code

```
$('input, textarea').placeholder();
```