# Default textbox message not working for Internet Explorer

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, placeholder

I am trying to display a default message as a placeholder for my textbox. When the user clicks, the default message disappears and an empty textbox is presented to the user - to enter whatever information he or she chooses to.

This works good for all browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) except for IE v9.

what is up with this?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" BackColor="Silver" 
                BorderColor="Silver" Height="20px" Style="margin-left: 6px" Width="160px" 
                placeholder = "Enter Member ID here." ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE9 doesn't support `placeholder` attribute from HTML5.
You can do it via Javascript or numerous plugins mentioned over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366021/placeholder-in-ie9).

Comment: I did 've the following added to my code already:-
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/blob/master/jquery.placeholder.js

Still no go.

Comment: Can you please help me figure this out?