# Watermark/Placeholder for text-field in backbone template

Tags: html, backbone.js

I need to set placeholder for text-field in my backbone view template. I did it in following way

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Enter Group Name">
```

but this is not working in IE9 and greater versions. I have googled around and found some java script plugin for achieving this in html but for working in IE for my template what needs to do? any specific workaround or solution for this problem

Comment: Duplication - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366021/placeholder-in-ie9

Comment: I am looking for a solution in backbone template

Comment: so what stops u use JQ plugin in Backbone ?

Comment: I am new to backbone and not know where I can use these plugins and  other javascript code. is there any after render event or where to write all these code?

Comment: u can use any JQ plugin in view after you have rendered view and appended html. `this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON())); this.$el.superPlugin({ make: 'cool' })`