# show placeholder even if x isn't clicked on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am using [span.js](http://umbraengineering.github.io/Placeholder/demos/span.html) for some of my placeholders, it is nice, but there is one issue. In IE9 when you focusing input it shows x icon on the right hand side, and after focus out I can see my placeholder only when I click on x icon. I want to make it work as placeholder works - when there is no value placeholder needs to show even when I haven't clicked on x in IE.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="fieldWrap">
  <label for="mobile_number">Mobile Number</label>
  <div class="intl-tel-input">
    <input name="Mobile Number" id="mobile_number" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: 48px; top: 16px; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 100000; cursor: text; background-color: transparent;">Mobile Number</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It is an IE9 thing. Check out this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366021/placeholder-in-ie9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched in many places for solution, but decided to use another jquery plugin for placeholder and it works fine now even on IE9, here is a link where you can found jquery plugin https://github.com/natalan/jquery.formLabels